# Why is my Bitcoin transaction not confirming today?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, network, confirmations, zero-confirmation

Please don't tell me that this also has something to do with this stupid Corona virus. First, it slashes the Bitcoin value in (less than) half. Then I can't order any groceries and have to sit here and starve. And then it somehow affects the Bitcoin network's ability to make transfers?

Hopefully, it has nothing to do with the Corona virus, but if not, how can it be that I still have "0 confirmations" and it says the dreaded words "memory pool" in my Bitcoin Core?

For the last "many months", every Bitcoin transaction has been very fast to confirm fully for me. Why is it suddenly acting up? Is everyone trading tons now even though the price is so low? Isn't it when it goes *up* that there's network congestion?

Comment: That. and the simple answer is there's lots of transactions at the moment for whatever reason.

Comment: The way the price *gets* low is by lots of people selling.  That takes just as much trading as getting it to go up.